# datetimepicker not working. Bootstrap. Laravel

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5

My date time picker is not working properly. I have no idea what is wrong. I have used following syntax:
Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
    <meta content="" name="description"/>
    <meta content="" name="author"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("assets/stylesheets/styles.css") }}" />
</head>
<body>

    @yield('body')
    <script src="{{ asset("assets/scripts/frontend.js") }}" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

View:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date of Birth</label>
                <div class='input-group date' id='dob' >
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="dob"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#dob').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
```

When i try to click on date icon. It just turns into text editor symbol. I cannot click on the icon. What's the problem here? Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should add `id='dob'` to the `<input>`, not `<div>`

Comment: Check your console logs, I bet you it says `datetimepicker is not a function`

Comment: console log? how can i do that?

Comment: For Opening the Console: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: Yeah it is sowing nothing. It throws an error Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery.min.js:3:6598
no element found in Javascript menu

Answer (score 0):

You need to be create custom click event for glyphicon-calendar.

Assign dob ID to text field.

Try This:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#dob').datetimepicker();
});


$(".glyphicon-calendar").click(function() {

  $("#dob").datepicker("show");

});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Date of Birth</label>
  <div class='input-group date'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="dob" id='dob' />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is still not working. When i try to click the calendar button it just changes into text icon. Could it be due to 
<script src="{{ asset("assets/scripts/frontend.js") }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
Or I have to add other scripts too.

Comment: I think problem is some where else.